# Does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{r}{n})$ imply $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

We know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{r}{n})$ implies $\int\limits_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$.

Then does $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}\frac{1}{n}f(\frac{r}{n})$ imply $\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx$?

Comment: With, "implies", do you mean "equals"? Is $f$ a [Riemann integrable function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) on $[0,1]$?

Comment: yes..."equals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as $f$ is a continuous, or Riemann integrable function, then the answer is yes. More is true: if $0 = x_0^{(n)} < x_1^{(n)} < \dots < x_{N(n)}^{(n)} = \frac{1}{2}$ are arbitrary partitions, such that the maximal length of a seqment in the partition $\max_{i} x_{i}^{(n)}-x_{i-1}^{(n)}$ goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, then you have:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N(n)} (x_{i} - x_{i-1}) f(x_i)  = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} f(x) dx$$
This is, roughtly speaking, the definition of Riemann integral. Your question is answered by taking $x_{i}^{(n)} = \frac{i}{n}$ (and perhaps adding an extra term for odd $n$, which doesn't change the limit).

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your "implies" is intended to mean, let $g(x)=2f(2x)$ (I assume that your $f$ is from a family of functions such that $g$ is automatically in the same family of functions, for example the family of continuous functions on $[0,1]$). And consider the subsequence of even $n=2m$ in $\lim_{n
\to\infty}$